# Why does MAXVA in xv6 source code differ from the value in the xv6 textbook?

Tags: xv6, virtual-address-space

Why is the MAXVA value defined differently in the xv6 textbook of MIT 6s081 and the xv6 source code? The textbook states that the maximum address is 2^38 - 1 = 0x3fffffffff, while the source code defines MAXVA as (1L << (9 + 9 + 9 + 12 - 1)), which seems to be missing the -1. Can anyone explain the discrepancy and which one is correct?

The following screenshot is from **xv6.pdf** describing MAXVA, look at the yellow highlighted sentence:
[image]

The following code snippet is from (kernel/kernel/riscv.h:348):

```c
// one beyond the highest possible virtual address.
// MAXVA is actually one bit less than the max allowed by
// Sv39, to avoid having to sign-extend virtual addresses
// that have the high bit set.
#define MAXVA (1L << (9 + 9 + 9 + 12 - 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last address available is `2^38-1`

The goal of `MAXVA` is that no address points to `2^38` or more.

That's how `MAXVA` is used:

We can check that in `vm.h`: Note that the address is compared to `MAXVA` with "greater on equal", not just "greater than".

```
grep MAXVA -n vm.c -A 1
88:  if(va >= MAXVA)
89-    panic("walk");
--
114:  if(va >= MAXVA)
115-    return 0;
```

It's also explained in risc.h, the discrepancy you see is explained at lines 360, 361:

```
   359  // one beyond the highest possible virtual address.
   360  // MAXVA is actually one bit less than the max allowed by
   361  // Sv39, to avoid having to sign-extend virtual addresses
   362  // that have the high bit set.
   363  #define MAXVA (1L << (9 + 9 + 9 + 12 - 1))
```